# How to make a Queue of download list and how schedule it

Tags: 12.04, wget, schedule, downloaders

1- How to make a queue of download-list in Wget ?

2- Is there any way to schedule a Queue in Wget ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Queue

You can make a list of URLs to download in a plain text file, then use wget -i list-of-urls-file.txt to fetch them.

## Scheduling

As for scheduling, wget does not have a scheduler.  Use cron instead.  You can learn more about cron with the commands `man 1 crontab` and `man 5 crontab`.  Here's an example session where I setup a cron job that runs wget nightly:

> $ crontab -e
>
> [editor appears]
>
> @midnight wget -i /home/user/list-of-urls-file.txt
>
> [save and quit editor]